# How to set amount in range of database mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database mysql which save 2 item

```
 id | count | count_max
  1 |   0   |    10 
  2 |   11  |    100
```

Then I fetch all and foreach array to get those count and count_max

If I put number 1000 how can to set the amount to 100 because of the max of foreach array is 100.

I already did this

```
$number = 1000;
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($res as $key => $value){
 if($number<$value['count']){
  $number = $value['count'];
  break;
 }elseif($number>$value['count_max']){
  $number = $value['count_max'];
  continue;
 }elseif($number<=$value['count'] && $number>=$value['count_max']){
  $number = $number;
  break;
 }
}
```

The result should be 100, but I got result 11.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: not clear what you're saying.

Comment: I input number 1000, but the result was 11 instead of giving me 100, because of my count max is 100 in database

Comment: You're overriding the ``number`` in the loop. Use a different variable say ``n`` and the result will be ``100``.

Comment: Within the loop instead of assigning new value to the ``$number`` variable, use a new variable, as ``$n = $value['count'];``, ``$n = $value['count_max'];`` and $n = $number`` respectively;